# gcc -fno-stack-protector option

Tags: c, gcc, stack, stack-overflow

I'm working on a school project, and basically we're trying to learn about stack overflows. Some sample code that I'm working on is basically: (trimmed down)

```
char test[10];
int i;
for (i=0;i < 10000;i++) {
    test[i] = 'a';
}
```

When I compile this with gcc, everything works all fine and dandy. Gcc automatically protects the stack and never lets it overflow outrageously. Now, if I try to use gcc -fno-stack-protector.... the exact same program runs. I even do a diff on the assembly files (the -S option) and they are identical. What gives? I searched through the man pages and there was no mention of the -fno-stack option... Everything online points to the -fno-stack-protector option, but I have not been able to recreate anything at all...

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure?  Mine gives (iff stack guard not disabled):

```
.L2:
        cmpl    $9999, -36(%rbp)
        jle     .L3
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
        je      .L5
        call    __stack_chk_fail
```

from

```
int test() {
char test[10];
int i;
for (i=0;i < 10000;i++) {
  test[i] = 'a';
 }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm. I've been looking into it, and it seems that though strangely enough stack protection is NOT enabled by default, so the -fno-stack-protector option does absolutely nothing. I have to use the -fstack-protector option to enable stack protection which now makes my application throw a segfault after being run. So stack protection causes an application to throw a segmentation fault, whereas no stack protection lets the code modify the stack at will?

Comment: depends on system (distro), it's better to count on "nothing is set unless you do set it". Also, some optim. flags set it off (-O3, don't think O2 does it).

Comment: @Glen That your program ran was a coincidence and is probably worse than a segfault. It was happily writing off the end of the array with stack protection disabled, you just didn't know about it (since there were no checks that you were in-bounds). It may have been overwriting the address of printf with delete_hard_drive or launch_the_missiles, and you just didn't know because you didn't call printf in this run. A loud crash is generally better than silently failing.

Comment: So to make sure it's on aff `-fstack-protector` it seems?